# passing json in json to spring controller

Tags: ajax, spring, kotlin

I am trying to pass json object to spring controller and I manage to do that, but value of one property is in json and I **think** that I have problem because of it. But there is no other way to pass that data. Code is below,
data class:

```
@Entity
data class Section(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        val id: Long = 0L,
        val name: String = "",
        var text: String,
        @ManyToOne
        var notebook: Notebook
)
```

Controller code:

```
@PutMapping("/sections/{id}")
fun updateSection(@RequestBody section: Section, @PathVariable id: Long): Section =
        sectionRepository.findById(id).map {
            it.text = section.text
            it.notebook = section.notebook
            sectionRepository.save(it)
        }.orElseThrow { SectionNotFoundException(id) }
```

javascript sending post to api:

```
function updateApi(data) {
    axios.put(MAIN_URL + 'sections/' + data.id, {
        data
    })
        .then(showChangesSaved())
        .catch(ShowErrorSync());

}


function saveSection() {
    var data = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("curr-section"));
    data.text = JSON.stringify(element.editor).toString();
    updateApi(data);
}
```

I get error like this:

```
2020-11-18 15:06:24.052  WARN 16172 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Instantiation of [simple type, class org.dn.model.Section] value failed for JSON property text due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter text which is a non-nullable type; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.MissingKotlinParameterException: Instantiation of [simple type, class org.dn.model.Section] value failed for JSON property text due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter text which is a non-nullable type
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 375] (through reference chain: org.dn.model.Section["text"])]
```

so text in element.editor is JSON formatted string and I need to pass it as it is to controller. Is there any way to do that? I tried searching, but I can't find json in json help...
Whole project is available on [github](https://www.github.com/FMusic/DevNotesApi/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your json looks like? If I check out your project and run the following two tests:

- one with `Section` as an object as request body
- one with `Section` as json

Both will succeed. So the problem might lie in your JSON:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class HttpRequestTest {
    @LocalServerPort
    private val port = 0

    @Autowired
    private val restTemplate: TestRestTemplate? = null
    @Test
    fun sectionAsObject() {
        val section = Section(0L, "2L", "text", Notebook(1L, "1", "2"))
        assertThat(restTemplate!!.put("http://localhost:$port/sections/123", section
                )).isNotNull
    }

    @Test
    fun sectionAsJson() {
        val sectionAsJson = """
            {
              "id": 0,
              "name": "aName",
              "text": "aText",
              "noteBook": {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "aName",
                "desc": "2"
              }
            }
        """.trimIndent()
        assertThat(restTemplate!!.put("http://localhost:$port/sections/123", sectionAsJson
        )).isNotNull
    }
}
```

BTW: it is not a pretty good habit to expose your database ids, which is considered to be a security risk as it exposes your database layer. Instead, you might want to use a functional unique key ;)

Comment: Thank you for tests, I didn't know how to write them for spring boot.. And it's true my json has a problem which I am trying to solve. It has one too many wrappers around section object.

Comment: No problem! Those tests are really valuable to point out the issue. Spring documents this stuff pretty well: https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/ ;) 
Did you try the JSON used in my test?